# Focus form in html is not blue i want it red

Tags: javascript, html, css

My trouble is that I can't create web form like this image :

[image]

How do I create a form where its focus is not blue like this photo, I just want to do it red

Comment: Please post the css and html code you have tried. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6nrvvpmb/2/) with shadow

```
 input:focus {

     outline-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Why outline is important?

Comment: i used another way to make it just removing outline and giving border. !important is used to force the element to get this style. In updated answer and jsfiddle i have removed that and changed only the outline color

Comment: Thank you But outline is little bold and border is pale

Comment: Border is good or outline?
And I like this photo have a little shade
Please see again it photo

Comment: The CSS outline property is a confusing property. When you first learn about it, it's hard to understand how it is even remotely different from the border property. The W3C explains it as having the following differences:

1.Outlines do not take up space.

2.Outlines may be non-rectangular.

Comment: can you write code searching in the web for example ?

Comment: can you be more clear ? firstly you should check my answer as correct and then you can create another question for something else because when other people watch this post they are searching only for this problem

Comment: check and read this please http://stackoverflow.com/tour . You are new here and you should learn some rules. You should mark as correct the answer that is correct. You have the jsfiddle in the answer that is working code that gives what you want

Comment: Yes i'm a new here Thank you for the rules

Comment: Marked your answer

Answer (score 0):

There should be a :active property in css for the form. change the color there and you should be all set. can i see the code?

Comment: Active for a second.
And then release the mouse again to form the first focus returns
Active mouse button for the former is that we
Initial focus is released when the form